# Terminal go crazy. Commands from other tabs displaying with duplicated multiple times chars

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome-terminator

Commands from other tabs displaying with duplicated chars, multiple times. I'm so confused because it happens even for passwords!

My actions:

1. I use terminator terminal emulator https://launchpad.net/terminator
2. open two tabs
3. start working in the first
4. switch to the second one and see this

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I  haven't used terminator in years.  Everyone I know uses tmux.  I suspect that terminator just isn't very stable.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/1318542 . what matters is to use the same group in both sides, and to use broadcast group or simply to use broadcast all. Could  reproduce it (on debian 9 with custom xfce): duplicates output, but not where I'm typing. Once I hit enter, the other side chokes on the bad command. Strange I don't remember having this problem in the past, but I stopped using it.

Comment: Works correctly when running inside a nested [Xephyr](https://manpages.debian.org/xserver-xephyr/Xephyr.1). So it depends on environment (DE, gtk etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is likely caused by an additional package (ibus) which could have been installed through another package as a dependency. This package (ibus) changes the keyboard broadcast of the system.

In my case ibus was installed as a dependency of zoom. More info: https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/862/terminator-terminal-inserting-each-character-twice-double-broadcast-multiple-windows

Stopping the ibus daemon (and removing the package) should solve this bug.

Answer (score -1):

> env -i DISPLAY=:0 terminator

i fix it

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Your answer is a bit terse and could be improved by explaining the issue, i.e., the underlying cause of the problem and why your solution correctly would resolve it for the user in the question.